# How do I build a YAML list using yq?

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I am trying to use Mike Farrah's `yq` utility to build YAML files from within a `bash` script. Below is an example of the template I'm using:

```
---
name: <name>
description: <description>
type: <type>
labels: [label]
data:
  - value: <value>
    operation: <operation>
    labelValues: [value]
```

The `labels` and `labelValues` fields are a list of strings. For example:

```
labels: [string1, string2, ...]
```

or

```
labels:
  - string1
  - string2
  - ...
```

To add some further complexity, the `data` field is a list of objects, consisting of the `value`, `operation` and `labelValues` fields.

I'm trying to figure out how to build the `labels` list, using a `bash` script array of values. Not having much luck. The closest I've gotten is with the following code:

The array:

```
$ echo ${labels[@]}
project group
```

The command:

```
for lbl in ${labels[@]}; do
  yq '.labels.[] |= "'$lbl'"' metric-spec-template.yaml
done
```

This is what I need:

```
---
name: <name>
description: <description>
type: <type>
labels: [project, group]
data:
  - value: <value>
    operation: <operation>
    labelValues: <labelValues>
```

This is what I get:

```
name: <name>
description: <description>
type: <type>
labels: [project]
data:
  - value: <value>
    operation: <operation>
    labelValues: <labelValues>
name: <name>
description: <description>
type: <type>
labels: [group]
data:
  - value: <value>
    operation: <operation>
    labelValues: <labelValues>
```

The user [guide](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is nicely written, but I can't figure out how to make this work as needed. I haven't even begun to think about how I would build the list of `data` items.

Are there any comprehensive tutorials on using `yq`? I haven't been able to find much beyond the main user guide.

Comment: You're going the wrong way about your code : as you are using a `for` loop, you're going to generate a new yml output every time

Comment: Tell me about it. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach fails because in the `for` loop you're calling `yq` separately for each item, but such a call never reads as input the results of the previous iteration, so there's nothing `yq` could "update". You should save the intermediary document in a shell variable, or save it to a temporary file, or directly update the source file itself (the latter two make use of the `--inplace` (or `-i`) flag).

```bash
# using a shell variable

declare -a labels=(project group)
doc="$(yq '.labels = []' template.yaml)" # resets array, stores in var
for lbl in "${labels[@]}"; do
  doc="$(lbl="$lbl" yq '.labels += strenv(lbl)' <<< "$doc")"
done
printf '%s\n' "$doc" # outputs result
```

```bash
# using a temporary file

declare -a labels=(project group)
tmp="$(mktemp)" # creates a temporary file
yq '.labels = []' template.yaml > "$tmp" # resets array, saves to temp file
for lbl in "${labels[@]}"; do
  lbl="$lbl" yq -i '.labels += strenv(lbl)' "$tmp" # modifies temp file
done
cat "$tmp"; rm -f "$tmp" # outputs result, removes temp file
```

```bash
# using the source file

declare -a labels=(project group)
yq -i '.labels = []' template.yaml # resets array, modifies src file
for lbl in "${labels[@]}"; do
  lbl="$lbl" yq -i '.labels += strenv(lbl)' template.yaml # modifies src file
done
cat template.yaml # outputs result from src file
```

Ideally, though, you should move the entire loop into `yq`, and provide to it all the data necessary for the iteration at once, so you'd end up with just one call to `yq` which should then also perform better.

Unfortunately, you cannot just import a bash array as a YAML array, as `yq` imports variables through the environment, and ["There isn't really a good way to encode an array variable into the environment"](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html) (by Chet Ramey, the current maintainer of bash).

Your remaining options would be:

- prepending the items with dashes, each on its separate line, so the resulting string can be conventionally imported using the environment, and interpreted by `yq` as another YAML input comprising a list of strings (Note that this is an ad-hoc improvident hit-or-miss YAML encoding which would likely break if an item contained certain special characters (e.g. line breaks) capable to invalidate the intended encoding.)
- converting the array just into a string of space-separated items, which could then be imported as such, and split back into an array by `yq` (Note that this still relies on the items not containing whitespace characters, but as you've used `echo ${labels[@]}` and `for lbl in ${labels[@]}; do` yourself without quoting the variables, it's fair to assume that they don't.)
- using another YAML processor that provides other means for data imports, like [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) or [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq), for example. The former converts between YAML and JSON, and then uses `jq` internally for the JSON processing, while the latter is a full rewrite of `jq` that additionally implements a YAML processor. Thus, both can make use of `jq`'s `--args` flag which allows for the provision of strings as arguments on the command line, which can then be accessed using the built-in `$ARGS` variable.

```bash
# using an ad-hoc YAML encoding

declare -a labels=(project group)
lbls="$(printf -- '- %s\n' "${labels[@]}")" yq '.labels = env(lbls)' template.yaml
```

```bash
# converting into a space-separated string

declare -a labels=(project group)
lbls="${labels[*]}" yq '.labels = strenv(lbls) / " "' template.yaml
```

```bash
# using another YAML processor, here kislyuk/yq or itchyny/gojq
# (aliasing is optional, it just illustrates that both use the same jq filter)

declare -a labels=(project group)
alias yq2='yq -y' # if using kislyuk/yq
alias yq2='gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output' # if using itchyny/gojq
yq2 '.labels = $ARGS.positional' template.yaml --args "${labels[@]}"
```